# Cached Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, caching

I have a problem in the application I am building. And I have read many threads about the similar problem and have applied the suggestion given in those threads. However, the problem persists hence I write this.

The setup for is as follows:

1. I have the 3 php files: `index.php`, `step_one.php` and `calculation.php`.
2. From the `index.php`, I successfully load the `step_one.php` via the Ajax call which is as follows:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
           var nocache = Math.random() * new Date().getTime() + Math.random();
               $("#bookings").click(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: 'step_one.php?cach='+nocache,
                       type: 'post',
                       cache: false,
                       success: function (data) {
                           $("#contentLeft").html(data);
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
   ```

Note: `step_one.php` is the html form.Then in `step_one.php`, I enter the data in the form and send the form data to `calculation.php` via another Ajax call that is as follows:

```
$("#viewprice").click(function () {
    var nocache = Math.random() * new Date().getTime() + Math.random();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'calculate_quote.php?cache=' + nocache,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: $("#stepOneForm").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".quote").append(data);
            $(".quote").show();
            document.getElementById("price").value = data;
        }
    });
});
```

The `calculation.php` file, calculates the price based on the data it receives and return the `json` to `step_one.php`. This is how I return `json` from `calculation.php`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
echo json_encode($data);
```

Note: The first time I click the `#viewprice` button, the price is correctly and successfully return to `step_one.php`. However, when in `step_one.php` I enter new data and re-click the `#viewprice` button, nothing is returned from `calculation.php`. And when I inspect the Network data, I see the `calculation.php` gets duplicated there and only the first Ajax call will the data in its response.

And this running in the local machine in xamp.
Would you please assist? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Should: `url: 'step_one.php?cach='+nocache,` be: `url: 'step_one.php?cache='+nocache,`?

Comment: @RyanVincent the name of the querystring doesn't matter so `cach` and `cache` will do the same thing (not caching the request) as long as the corresponding *value** is random so this should not be the issue. I think it has to do with the way the OP loads a request and the scripts for it, yet I'm missing the full case here (posting what you think is relevant leaves out a lot of **relevant** code other devs need to help.)

Comment: @semu I would first check to see if the actions actually happen in JS (e.g. the right *events* get fired) and you can do this by placing `console.log('got here')` in your clickhandler for `$('#viewprice')` - This way, whenever you click that button with the console / devtools open you'll see 'got here' if the event fires so you'll know if it's somewhere in that handler or not. You can do this for every handler that is involved to find a bug much faster and perhaps solve your problem entirely!

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, the code that I left out is html for form design and php code of `calculation.php` that is used to calculate price and assign is to `$data` variable before passing that variable to `json_encode` function.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, the _events_ are successfully fired for every click. I checked this by using Google Chrome **developer tools**

Comment: Alright, so if it's not in the AJAX calls then something else is happening. Maybe to the response? If the response http status is `200` that doesn't mean your request actually contains data or suitable data anyways. If you could post your HTML we might be able to help you out a bit more (and PHP would be lovely too but **strip sensitive info first!**)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, thanks for your last comment; it helped to change focus and at another direction which is my php code. And I found the bug. I have posted the answer, should someone else encounter almost the same logical error.

Comment: @Semu no problem at all! Glad you found the error and I'm actually really pleased to see you found the bug in a completely different area than what you expected ;) Good luck developing!

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug that was giving me headache. It was a **logical** error.

**Background**

I use tokens in my forms for security reason. So for each form, I generate a token on page load and store it in the session. Then when the form sends its data (including the token), I first check if the received token is in the session - if the token is found, I then use the receives values and use them to compute `$data` which I then pass it to `json_encode` function. After the token is found, I **delete** it.

So, the `calculation.php` was **not** cached as my Ajax code is correct. Instead, the problem was when I resend the form data for re-calculation. During resend, the token in the session has already been deleted; therefore, the token I send with the form data could not be found in the session. Hence, data not computed and nothing is return.

Answer (score 0):

[Caching Ajax POST requests](http://www.einternals.com/blog/web-development/ios6-0-caching-ajax-post-requests)

Think the above link will be useful >>>